# np.arange strange behavior - numeric problems

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numeric

I want to shift the zero `t=0` to the point `idx_null = 53538` and the length of the time is `62468`.

This is the code which I tried:

```
dt = 3.1e-10

len(np.arange(-idx_null*dt,(len(t)-idx_null)*dt,dt))
Out  [21]: 62468

dt = 3.3e-10

len(np.arange(-idx_null*dt,(len(t)-idx_null)*dt,dt))
Out  [23]: 62468

dt = 3.2e-10

len(np.arange(-idx_null*dt,(len(t)-idx_null)*dt,dt))
Out  [25]: 62469
```

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Check the [docs of np.arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html). There is a warning about a numerically unstable output and they advise to use [np.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) instead.

Comment: `np.arange(-idx_null, len(t)-idx_null) * dt` likely works better.

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good idea. I solved the problem with np.linspace. But I would like to know what is happening there to prevent failures in future work.